# In football, are there any post-match repercussions for not upholding the spirit of the game?

Tags: rules, football

These include offenses that are committed during the game, but not penalized by the referee.

- Feigning an injury
- Obstructing the vision of the referee during a key moment
- Damaging the ball
- Fighting with teammates
- A constant cycle of having the keeper throw the ball to a teammate and having a teammate head it back to the keeper's hands

By post match repercussions I imply disciplinary actions taken by the football association against the player(s).

Comment: Not included in your list, but Andreas Möller got suspended for two games in 1995 for diving.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial question here is "did the referee see the incident?"; if the referee saw the incident, then there is nothing that can be done; this falls under the principle of the "the referee's decision is final". If the referee did not see the incident, then governing bodies will take action as they see fit under their "bringing the game into disrepute" regulations.

Note that everything in your list should be penalised by the referee if they see it; the fourth is a sending off for violent conduct (perhaps most famously, [Lee Bowyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_Bowyer#Newcastle_United)), and all the rest would be at least a caution for unsporting conduct.

Comment: I think the last one would be counted as time-wasting rather than unsporting conduct, but the outcome would be the same (i.e. yellow cards for both players involved).

Comment: @F1Krazy My understanding was "tricks" to get around the backpass rule are unsporting conduct; the "time-wasting" offence is "delaying the restart of play" (Law 12.3) so I don't think can apply here as the ball is in play. But as you say, doesn't really matter very much.